# How to convert JSOn object to JSonArray in php

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSon object result and i want to convert it to JSonARray:

`{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration":"59min","parking_name":"asass"}}
{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"100","parking_duration":"22min","parking_name":"SDSDASDAS"}}`

OUTPUT i need is like the following , i need all result to be in one array 
 `[{"error":false,"user":{...}}, {"error":false,"user":{...}}]`    :

`[{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"500","parking_duration":"59min","parking_name":"asass"}},
{"error":false,"user":{"paid_amount":"100","parking_duration":"22min","parking_name":"SDSDASDAS"}}]`

Php code:

```
    .......
 // json response array
 $response = array("error" => FALSE);

 if (isset($_POST['plate_no'])) {

    // receiving the post params
      $plate_no = $_POST['plate_no']; 
   // get the user 
   $usersArr = $db->getDriverHistory($plate_no);

    if ($usersArr != false) {
     foreach($usersArr as $key=>$user){

    // use is found
   $response[$key]["error"] = FALSE;
  $response[$key]["user"]["paid_amount"] = $user["paid_amount"];
  $response[$key]["user"]["parking_duration"] = $user["parking_duration"];
  $response[$key]["user"]["parking_name"] = $user["parking_name"];
   $response = $response[$key];

  echo json_encode($response), "<br>";

      } 
    }
   .....
```

Comment: `echo` after `foreach`.

Comment: Why not just take the first string and wrap it in the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace last line with given below:

```
$data[] = $response[$key];
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This don't wrap it in [ ]